# Modal Popup closes on Postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

There popup modal which has different pizza sizes as radio button and bellow that a select flavor List Box which shows flavor according to the sizes. I want to show flavor according to sizes on selected change of radio button. But the popup modal closes. I tried it with jquery and also  ScriptManager and UpdatePanel but it then don't allow to select other sizes only default is selected (small size is selected).

---

### ASP.Net

```
<head>
<body>
<form>

  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pizzaModal">
   <p>Pizza</p>
  <img src="../dist/img/dashboardIcons/pizza.png" width="70" height="70" />
  <div class="modal fade" id="pizzaModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
        label="Close">
         </button>
       </div>

<div class="modal-body">

 <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="card card-danger">
     <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">Select Size</h3>
      </div>

     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblPizza_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"> 
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

  </div>
  </div>

  <h3 class="card-title">Select Flavour</h3>
  </div>
   <div class="card-body">
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ListBox1" SelectionMode="Multiple"> 
</asp:ListBox>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSavePizza">Save 
  changes</button>
 </div>
 </div>

     </div>

    </div>
</form>
 </body>
 </head>
```

### ## Backend Code ##

```
enter code here

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        string pizzaModal = lblPizzaModal.Text;

        if (pizzaModal != "" && pizzaModal != null)
        {
            BindSizeList(pizzaModal, rblPizza);
            BindFlavourList(pizzaModal, lstBoxPizzaFlavour);
        }
    }

else
    {
        int a = 10;
       //need to stop modal from closing in this section

    }
}

 protected void rblPizza_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new 
   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCON"].ToString());

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_SelectProductFlavourSize", con);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SizeId", 1);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    adpt.Fill(ds);
    lstBoxPizzaFlavour.DataSource = ds;
    lstBoxPizzaFlavour.DataTextField = "Name";
    lstBoxPizzaFlavour.DataValueField = "FlavourId";
    lstBoxPizzaFlavour.DataBind();
    con.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Looks like the radio button causes a postback: RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
   RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblPizza_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: i want the AutoPostBack="true"  just don't want the modal to close after postback.

Comment: Postback is going to refresh the page and close it out. what you could do is when the postback happens update a hidden field with a value, then when the page loads have jquery look at that hidden field. if populated, means there as a postback, have it retrigger the popup. this way after the postback it will popup again.

Answer (score -1):

You must save the modal state because whenever a `postback` call is triggered, the `javascript/html` is reloaded on the page and you may `fallback` to the default state of the page. What I would recommend is to manually add the class(which is responsible for showing the modal) each time when the page is posted back from the `C# codebehind`.

**EDIT 1:**
I am not sure why it is being down voted without briefing the reason of it?

---

**EDIT 2:** *2020-05-02*

After 2 whole years, I decided to add an update to this question without removing the above stupid suggestion, I think now I know why it was down voted. So, Here is my answer:

It is highly recommended to use `AJAX` calls to post your form that you have in popup or you can use `UpdatePanels` in your asp.net project. Because whenever you click a server side button it posts data back to the server and it is a synchronous process so you should use `UpdatePanels` to post your form.

1. Add a `ScriptManager` tag in the top of your `aspx` page. (Remember, `ScriptManager` should go into your page markup only once that means it should not be there in the master page as well, and if it is in the master page, you should not add it into the child page, it will work without adding the `ScriptManager` tag in markup of child page)
2. Wrap your popup control markup inside of the UpdatePanel, something like below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPopup">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- Your Markup for Popup -->
    <ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And If you want to push your data using `AJAX` call, I would recommend you to go through [this tutorial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) to see how to send data to the C# code behind with out posting back the form.